# Perform backup and restoration using percona xtrabackup on mysql 8.0.22

Tags: mysql, database, docker, backup, percona

I am a beginner in backups and restorations.

I want to perform a backup and restoration using Percona XtraBackup 8.0.14 on MySQL 8.0.22. According to
https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/10/23/mysql-new-releases-and-percona-xtrabackup-incompatibilities/, it seems that MySQL 8.0.22 is not compatible with percona 8.0.14.
Anyone know how can I perform the backups and restoration of my DB ?
I thought about downgrading MySQL from 8.0.22 to 8.0.21 but seems blurry in my
mind.

Notes: MySQL and percona are running in Docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

Percona XtraBackup 8.0.22-15.0 has been release which supports MySQL 8.0.22. Please find below links for more details

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/release-notes/8.0/8.0.22-15.0.html

https://jira.percona.com/browse/PXB-2314

Comment: Thanks @ROHIT KHURANA, really good to know.